# Help me take vengeance on the Undead

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-creation, multi-classing, undead

What tools/feats/traits can a pc (specifically an Alchemist) who is not a Ranger, Cleric, or Paladin, use to become more effective at exacting vengeance on the plague of the Undead? The only thing I've come up with so far is to multi-class into one of those three.

I have scoured the web and what books I have available for answers and have found very little to satisfy me.

- The Crypt Breaker alchemist archetype had too many downsides to normal game-play.
- The Corpse Hunter Ranger archetype looks promising so I have settled for 1 rank in that, for the time being.
- I found two Religion traits that would help: Corpse Hunter and Undead Slayer. the former gives +1 to hit undead, and the latter gives +1 to weapon damage rolls against undead.
- There are some alchemical items listed in the Undead Slayer's Handbook that I thought were interesting and possibly useful, however, I thought most of the stuff in that book was not what I was looking for.

Is there anything I'm missing? I would like to know every tool and feature at my disposal, (barring control or raising of undead creatures, as Pharasma would take a pretty dim view of that)

Comment: Just to be clear...you don't want to involve Ranger, even though you appear to have decided to take a level in it? What is your current build? Why the limits on Ranger, Cleric and Paladin - is Oracle or Inquisitor acceptable? Any particular sort of undead?

Comment: All undead, as my character's deity sees the undead as Abhorrent. This is why I was thinking about Clerics and Paladins (because of association of my character's powers against undead with a deity) And rangers, just because of the favored enemy feature.  

As it stands, my vision of the character has exploded and settled pretty well as the day has gone on. I have decided to go Alchemist 13, Sentinel 6, Ranger 1. Glaring errors with this path?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than multiclassing you could switch your archetype to [Crypt Breaker](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/alchemist/archetypes/paizo-alchemist-archetypes/crypt-breaker) It's an alchemist archetype that focuses on diving into crypts and destroying undead giving you trapfinding as well as making your bombs deal more damage towards undead.

Comment: Yes, I looked at that archetype and was rather unimpressed. You see, I want to be particularly good at fighting undead, not *only* good at fighting undead. Not only that, but I really prefer the standard mutagen (with its various discoverable upgrades) over the silly sense-enhancing waffle the crypt-breaker produces.

Overall, the negative ways it would change my playstyle far outweigh the small boost to damage against undead/constructs (and subsequent loss of bomb damage to every other creature type). Thank you, though. This is the sort of answer I'm looking for

Answer (score 3):

Knowledge (Religion) would let your character know the weaknesses of a particular undead.

The Feat:  [Ghostslayer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/ghostslayer-combat/) is good and only needs BAB: 1 and Know.(Religion): 1

> **Benefit(s)**: As a swift action, you can imbue a weapon you wield with
>   spiritual energies for 1 round. An imbued weapon damages incorporeal
>   creatures as though it were magical. If the imbued weapon has an
>   enhancement bonus of +2 or greater, it functions as a ghost touch
>   weapon.
>
> A weapon imbued in this way can deal precision damage (such as sneak
>   attack damage) to incorporeal creatures.

As has been mentioned, Great Fortitude and Iron Will will be useful to counteract some of their special abilities.

Also, either have a weapon with all three damage types (slashing, blunt, and piercing) or have multiple weapons.

Comment: This is good advice. I have already started putting ranks into Knowledge Religion so that I can get the feat Deific Obedience feat. I will definitely look into the Ghostslayer as well.